# Trying to use a new libstdc++ on an old machine causes error

Tags: c++, version, libstdc++

I have a program that I compile using CMake on machine A but I want to run it on an older machine B. When I do so I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./program)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./program)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./program)
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150409/) and I think the best way to resolve my problem would be to copy the newer version to machine B. So I copied `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` (and `libstdc++.so.6.0.14`) from A to `~/lib` on B and did

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

afterwards. When starting my program I now get

```
Floating point exception
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: I know this sucks and is not what you want to hear, but if you need to run code on older glibc/libstdc++, compile the code on a system with the oldest version you need. Old libraries and new compiles are just not compatible, and replacing or superceding libc/libstdc++ on Linux mostly stabs you in the back when you least expect it.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, you need to have the newer `libstdc++.so.6` present on the older system, and tell the dynamic linker how to find it.

See [How do I insure that the dynamically linked library will be found?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths) in the libstdc++ FAQ  and [Finding Dynamic or Shared Libraries](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic) in the manual for details of how to make sure it's found, with several options. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is just one of the options.

The floating point exception shouldn't be related to libstdc++, you'll need to use a debugger to find where that comes from and get more details.