# R Error Message on a Linux Machine

Tags: linux, r, runtime-error

So I am trying to run the following code in R

```
command = paste("./WMCSim",HTM,sc,HTM,fa,ccm,sep=" ")
setwd("/home/build")
system(command)
```

and then I got the following error

```
./WMCSim: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./WMCSim)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this problem? I usually run R on a windows machine so I am a little confused debugging it on Linux.  Thanks!

Comment: What flavour of Linux are you running?

Comment: how you are running it? what is the command?

Comment: @Satish I am running it by opening `R` in terminal.  Should I be saving my `R` script and running it suing some sort of command?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150409/libstdc-glibcxx-version-errors)

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu it does seem to be on topic but how can I incorporate that answer into the R environment context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this-
Save your R script in a file(example `a.R`)

If you want the output to print to the terminal it is best to use Rscript

```
Rscript a.R
```

Note that when using `R CMD BATCH a.R` that instead of redirecting output to standard out and displaying on the terminal a new file called a.Rout will be created.

```
R CMD BATCH a.R
# Check the output
cat a.Rout
```